# QT Designer: .ui > .py

Tags: python, pyqt4

У меня есть отрисованный в Дизайнере .ui файл. Как мне скомпилить его в .py? Читал, что нужно сделать какой-то батник, но конкретно какой и как вообще это работает - в упор не понимаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке scripts инсталляции Python есть скрипт uic (или pyuic), который конвертирует .ui файлы в питоновский код

Answer (score 0):

Все, ушел глубже в гугл и проблема решилась. Удалить вопрос еще по статусу не могу.